# Subtract a tuple from an int

Tags: python

I keep getting a error that tuple cant be subtracted from a integer. I am trying to add all inputs to a list, then add all contents together and subtract it from the total monthly cash flow.

```
def budget_50_total():
    list=[]
    monthly = int(input("How much is your monthly cash flow "))
    essential = budget_50(monthly)
    print(essential)
    # Do calculation for 50%
    print("Please enter your essential expenses! ")
    house = int(input("How much is your housing for month: "))
    utilities = int(input("How much is your utilities this month 'gas, power, etc': "))
    grocery = int(input("How much is your groceries for month "))
    health = int(input("How much is your health insurance for the month "))
    car = int(input("How much is your car payment"))

    for i in range(1):
        data = house, utilities,grocery,health,car
        list.append(data)
        print(list)
    total = sum(list)
    print(total)
    total2 = essential - total
    print(total2)
```

Comment: Can you share the code of budget_50 ? Why a loop of range(1) ?, Also never use a built-in name for a variable, like `list`

Comment: What do the tuples look like? Can you show us an example of the calculation it's trying to make with actual values?

Comment: Try changing `list.append(data)` to `list.append(sum(data))`

Comment: Because when you append `data` to `list`, you are appending a tuple to a list and then, summing a list of tuples. I think that caused the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line creates a tuple:

```
data = house, utilities,grocery,health,car
```

Then you add the tuple to the list in the next line. You won't be able to sum a list of tuple. You could however do

```
data = house, utilities,grocery,health,car
print(data)
total = sum(data)
```

However, your error "tuple cant be subtracted from a integer" is likely caused by your calculation for `total2` as that is your only subtraction in the code shown. It's impossible to say what the issue is here without knowing what `essential` is.

Comment: `sum(data)` will work too, no need to convert to a `list`.

Comment: Thank you the sum(list(data)) would not work said list is not callable but the suggestion sum(data) does exactly what I needed thanks again

Comment: @HoseaMedia You get the "list is not callable" error because by making a variable called "list" you have redefined what was originally a callable object.

Comment: @Błotosmętek Edited the answer to use your method. It's cleaner

Answer (score 0):

You can use a for loop to add the sum of each tuple in list to the total:

```
total = 0
for x in list:
    total += sum(x)
```